# Amazon RDS Multi-AZ scaling downtime

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, failover

I have a question about scaling up MySql RDS - Multi-AZ downtime.

I think firstly Amazon will scale the Slave, then do fail over (  there is a downtime here ). then it will scale the master.

my question: is fail over the only downtime?. is there any downtime to redirect the requests back from the slave to the master after scaling the master.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a Multi-AZ setup, any change you make to the instance will first be done on the standby instance. Then, failover will occur (during this phase your application won't be able to connect to the database) and the change will be applied to the primary instance. The failover is the only downtime.

More information: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZ.html